# What makes a GPU inferior to CPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu

A computer is supposed to crunch numbers and then output the result data. To make this happen we program the computer to do what we want. This can be done by writing a program in high level language like C and others which is then converted into the machine code for that processor.

The CPU and GPU are both programmable processors. I am also aware that GPU contains a lot of processing power that CPU does not have due to a large number of parallel number crunching modules. Now my question is, since GPU is also programmable like CPU and has more processing power, why not just run the OS and all programs on the GPU?

Comment: GPU is not "inferior." It is _specialized._ (Answers below talk about its special job.)

Comment: I don't know why I got so many down votes, the question is simply that why not run Windows and Linux on the GPU since it is supposed to have a higher processing power than CPU, or so I understand. The answers to deal with this aspect to an extent but I guess to get the complete answer, I will have to compare the CPU and GPU architectures side by side.

Comment: Tough crowd here it seems. Indeed, comparing architectures is a good choice. A probative question would be, “How does each architecture deal with interrupts?“ GPUs tend to work on tasks in ‘waves’, and if it has to sideline a ‘wave’ to respond to an interrupt, that’s a lot of work-state lost. CPUs don’t have so much state, and some even support hyper threading which further reduces the context switch penalty.

Comment: Isn't the fact that GPU can do many things in parallel the same as it running multiple threads in parallel?

Comment: The gpu can do the same operation on many data in parallel. Its like having 10 sausage machines in parallel. Crank that handle you get 10x the number of sausages. You want nachos? Too bad, we’re doing sausages by the zillion today.

Comment: I'd assume the downvotes are because the premise of the question is invalid: a GPU is not inferior to a CPU, because they are not trying to do the same task. They're designed and optimized for different things. A CPU would be terrible at doing the job of a GPU, and a GPU would be terrible at doing the job of a CPU.

Comment: FWIW I gave a +1.

Comment: I have firsthand experience trying to run an OS on a VLIW media processor. Painful. The second gen got an ARM core to do that.

Comment: @quantum231 -- a GPU isn't the same as multiple threads; the GPU does **the same thing** on many data sets **simultaneously**. Multiple threads can do **different** things.

Comment: VTC cleared - 4 good answers to answerable question.

Answer (score 6):

Why is a cargo ship inferior to a cargo plane?

GPUs can compute many tasks in parallel (all at once). However, if you were to assign any one of those tasks to a CPU, the CPU would complete it much faster.

For narrow, complex tasks the CPU is the way to go. For wide, simple tasks the GPU is great.

Comment: Better analogy would be container ship vs. cruise ship. Both get lots of stuff from point A to point B. But the container ship does best with a lot of nearly identical boxes and the cruise ship does best with people - and provides a lot more services (food, swimming pool, entertainment) for those people. The people won't be happen on the container ship. The cargo would do fine on the cruise ship (it has no feelings) but wouldn't get there as efficiently as on the container ship.

Answer (score 5):

Different tools for different problems.

The GPU is optimized for tasks that are repetitive, predictable, compute-intensive, and divisible into parallel threads. This covers not only the operations one finds in graphics, but also other high-performance computing tasks such as signal processing, modeling, and artificial intelligence.

GPUs are an evolution of what were known as *vector processors*, that is, architectures that were streamlined for doing multiple math operations per cycle using parallelism and/or deep pipelining. Compared to a CPU, they trade latency and flexibility for throughput. Additionally, GPUs add special instruction types for supporting pixel processing such as raster ops, z-buffer, shading, texture map and so forth. OpenGL and other graphics libraries are built on these capabilities.

Since their introduction, there have been several architecture approaches in GPU-land, including fixed pipelines in early chips, to VLIW, and more recently, multiple-SIMD architectures which serve to increase throughput while balancing flexibility for more generic compute workloads.

More here: https://www.rastergrid.com/blog/gpu-tech/2022/02/simd-in-the-gpu-world/

The CPU on the other hand is optimized for general computing, with workloads that span large virtual memory spaces and multiple, non-divisible stochastic threads. While many CPUs also feature some pipelining, parallelism and math acceleration, they don’t take it to the extreme that GPUs do, instead emphasizing responsive performance on less compute-bound tasks.

CPUs are designed for low latency, fast task switching and low branching penalties, making them better suited for the time-sensitive stochastic workloads expected of an OS, including interrupts and device drivers.

GPU tasks can be run efficiently on a modern CPU, which itself will have some math acceleration and vector processing capabilities. They will take longer than a GPU as they will be compute and/or I/O bound. Basic 3D shading for example will easily consume 100% of even the fastest CPU as it requires both vector operations and pixel manipulation, stressing the math units and I/O units, respectively.

On the other hand, CPU-oriented workloads such as running an OS will not make efficient use of the GPU because OS tasks don’t tend to parallelize well. This is because OS tasks are smaller (more fine-grained) with lots of branches and stack activity, as well as being stochastic in nature. The frequent branches and stack I/O will cause a lot of stalls and pipeline flushes, and thus a lot of wasted cycles in the GPU.

Over time, GPUs have added more general (scalar) computing capabilities in response to their expanding role in high-performance computing. Nevertheless, they’re still ungainly beasts when they’re forced to switch tasks because they have so much internal state in their parallel compute pipelines.

Stated another way, interrupting a GPU is bit like asking a bus to stop, unload all its passengers, pick up one special high-importance passenger and take them to their destination, then go back and load up the sidelined passengers and continue on its route. So high latency, heavy context switch penalty, but high throughput so long as you don’t disturb its flow.

The CPU is more like a taxi: able to respond quickly, but can only carry a few passengers at a time. So it has low latency, low context switch overhead but lower throughput.

Now, it is possible for the CPU to leverage the GPU for *some* of its tasks. For example, network packet processing can benefit from using the GPU’s wide data I/O bandwidth and fast parallel scalar math. More here: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/video/gputechconf/gtc/2019/presentation/s9730-packet-processing-on-gpu-at-100gbe-line-rate.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Technically, a GPU is optimized to crunch numbers while a CPU is primarily used to make decisions. Making decisions is an umbrella term that includes things such as branching and context switching which both allow management of many disparate tasks, as opposed to sequentially running straight through the code from beginning to end.

A CPU has some basic number added to it since this is required in many tasks but this is not what they are designed around.

The numbers that a GPU is expected to crunch are tasks where the dependencies allow the parallelism. Math tasks that can't be parallelized result in a bunch of wasted hardware in a GPU.

Then there is a third approach: A DSP which is more like a number crunching CPU. A DSP is also optimized to do number crunching like a GPU, but in a more sequential than parallel way like a CPU would, and often with higher precision. However, what makes a DSP different from a CPU is that it has been optimized to crunch numbers rather than making decisions. As such, a DSP is intended to perform just one calculation task continuously and, more or less, run straight through its code from beginning to end with little branching.

I guess the basic point is that the ability to make decisions and take different actions based on those decisions is not something to be taken for granted. Because when *humans* say that computers are number crunchers, they are taking decision-making for granted because it is simple and natural for humans to make decisions, but unnatural and difficult to do calculations.

Comment: A witty post, especially the "but unnatural and difficult to do calculations" part. My 2¢: humans, to offload calculation tasks from your brains, use peripheral neural ganglia of your body!

Answer (score 3):

With patience, accuracy, strength you can sometimes pound a nail in using a screwdriver.  But it is a task better suited for a hammer.  You can pound a screw in with a hammer but the holding power is far inferior than using a screwdriver.

CPU and GPU are very high level terms, but as you get into specific implementations you find that some GPU cannot even do generic operations, they could not run normal code, some can only crunch numbers.  But their instructions and logic are implemented to do these operations better than equivalent solutions on a generic CPU.

Comment: So the basic idea is that GPU can just crunch numbers quite fast but its architecture lacks the features that are not considered essential in a processor to lets say run windows OS. This is the reason that we still use CPU and do not run everything on GPU. This is what I have learnt so far. It is clear now that my understanding about GPU was flawed. Having an accumulator with some arithmetic and logic operations in an ISA is not enough to run modern OS and applications on it.

Comment: It is more than that.  A general purpose cpu is designed for general purpose things.  A gpu is designed for something specific.  Some, could technically run an os, some cannot.  it is like a semi truck with a trailer with 10,000 pounds of payload.  and a race car.  the semi truck, technically can drive around a race track. The race car, technically could get you from one town to another, and even haul 10,000 pounds, a little at a time each trip...but would you use them that way?

Comment: The gpu is not inferior in any way.  It is significantly superior at its job, and compared to the gpu the cpu is superior at its job.  They are just built for different jobs, otherwise they would have the same name.

Comment: just go get documentation for a few examples of each, it should be obvious.